# $f:M \to Q$ a monomorphism with $Q$ injective and $g:M \to N$ an essential morphism, then there exists a mono $\bar{g}: N \to Q$ such $\bar{g} g= f$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, injective-module

This one is based on (A) of the answer of this previous question

[For a projective cover $(\sigma, P)$ of a module $M$, $P$ is indecomposable implies $M$ is indecomposable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695980/for-a-projective-cover-sigma-p-of-a-module-m-p-is-indecomposable-impl)

Let $Q$ be an injective module and $f:M \to Q$ a monomorphism. Prove that if $g:M \to N$ is an essential monomorphism, there exists a monomorphism $\bar{g}: N \to Q$ such $\bar{g} g= f$.

As $g: M \to N$ is essential monomorphism I got that $g(M)$ is an essential submodule of $N$ which means that  for every submodule $N' \leq N$ such $g(M) \cap N' = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ then $N'= \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Also, as $g:M \to N$ is injective(essential monomorphism) with $Q$ injective module by hypothesis I got that there is a morphism $\bar{g}:N \to Q$ such $\bar{g} g= f$ still cannot prove that this $\bar{g}$ is injective

First lets prove $\ker(\bar{g}) \cap g(M)= \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Let's take $x \in \ker(\bar{g}) \cap g(M)$. As $x \in g(M)$ there is some $x' \in M$ such $g(x')=x$ but as $x \in \ker(\bar{g})$ then $g \bar{g}(x')= g (x)=0$ so by commutativity $f(x')=0$, but as $f$ is injective by hypothesis $x'=0$. Then $x=g(x')=0$. So by the essential hypothesis $\ker(\bar{g})= \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ proving $\bar{g}$ injective.

Comment: Let $N'=\operatorname{Ker} \overline{g}$. What can you say about $N'\cap g(M)$?

Comment: Well, I would like to see that $N' \cap g(M)= \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ so by the essential hypothesis got that $N'= \lbrace 0 \rbrace$  to finish. But I cannot see this intersection is $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$, I tried by contradiction but  still cannot get it @Mohan

Comment: Already proved the exercise with your hint. Edited the original question, please let me know if there are some flaws at it. @Mohan

Comment: @Cos just to point out that this is *exactly* the contents of the "exercise (A)" that I gave you a week ago on your last question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695980/for-a-projective-cover-sigma-p-of-a-module-m-p-is-indecomposable-impl.  I think it would be helpful for you to link your related previous questions in your posts.

Comment: Sorry, already edited the original question @BadamBaplan. Still havent worked on the uniform module exercise as Im a little busy with other module problems. But as I said it, I wil try that for sure as im also curious about uniform modules.